# unable to mount location: message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

Tags: mount, samba, mac, file-sharing

I have Raspberry PI 3 b+ running Ubuntu Mate 18 and a macbook pro running latest OS. I'm trying to share folders between them anonymous/ guest via SMB.

However, Although I can see and access the shared folders when I login via a registered account. When trying to login/ connect as anonymous/ guest I get the subject error.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966/7 or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with MATE

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the feedback. Tried installing 20 but it was tough on the hardware. so I installed 16 and upgraded. I'm gonna attempt it again.

Comment: Ubuntu products using the *year* format (16, 20) are different systems to those using the *year.month* format... ie. Ubuntu Core 20 is a different system (a *flavor*) of the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server system from which it came.   20 & 20.04 are different Ubuntu products.